# What's the name of this tube insert for mounting tubes perpendicularly to a surface with hidden bolts?

Tags: pipe, mounting, bolts

I want to build a couple of cat scratch posts that can be mounted perpendicularly to a wall and used by cats as steps. I was thinking about using PVC or thick cardboard pipes/tubes, and how I could mount them to a wall so that the screws are hidden. I had a couple of ideas, and then I checked how ready-made products like this are constructed. Most often, I've seen them mounted to a wooden or plywood board with a double-threaded bolt, and then the board is mounted to the wall. To achieve this, there needs to be a threading for the bolt on the tube's side. I've observed what appear to be inserts with such threading in ready-made products (images below).

I assume these are inserts that are glued in, rather than being integral parts of the tube. They seem like something that can be purchased separately, not custom-made parts. I wanted to find similar parts but without success. I've tried multiple Google queries, such as "threaded pipe/tube inserts," "plastic tube inserts," "threaded tube plugs," etc. The closest I could find were adjustable leg inserts for furniture, but they are smaller in diameter. A Google image search did not help me either.

I considered that they might be regular plastic inserts with threading drilled in, but I could not find such inserts either, only thin plugs.

I know I can approach the problem of wall mounting in another way, but it bothers me that I could not find these parts, hence the question.

[image: plastic insert 2]

[image: plastic insert 1]

Comment: Threaded insert?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it's too vague.  As you say, the obvious way to do this is with wood and two-ended screws.  If you want to do it with cardboard, ask that.  If you want to use PVC drain pipe, ask that.  Tell us the diameter.  Ask how to solve a specific problem.  The picture of a commercially made product is not terribly helpful.  As it is, you'll get a huge inventory of every possible threaded anything, which does not make for a good Question here.

Comment: The nut is easy. What's the 0/-106 cap called?

Comment: Go to YouTube and look for "Floating Shelves." There are multiple solutions for the same type of issue that you have here. that is to say, hanging items perpendicular on a wall strong enough to hold shelves (or cats jumping)

Answer (score 4):

you'll probably have to make your own.  eg cut a round plug from some construction lumber using a hole saw. enlarge the pilot hole and fit a spiked tee nut to the inside-tube face of the plug

[image: Zenith M8 tee nut]

glue the assembly into the end of the tube using epoxy

Comment: If using tee nuts, the strongest connection will be if the tee nuts is on the inside surface of the hole in the plug rather than the outside, so it would have to pull through rather than pulling out. The connection between plug and tube would probably fail first.

Comment: As a note: Depending on the use case and torque expected, I've seen people put a small screw into the substrate holding the tee nut to _ensure_ the nut doesn't rip out when the bolt is twisted into the threads.

Comment: the nut should be on the away-from-wall (inside of tube)  face of the wood so that tightening the bolt secures the nut more,  if the wood is too thick countersink it with a spade bit,

Comment: but yes there is a risk of the nut escaping if handled roughly during installation, and a small screw or two would mitigate that.

Answer (score 3):

The name I see used so often is:

**nutserts**

Or rivetnuts but they tend to be used in sheet metal type applications.

Comment: That's the name of the thing in the thing. What's the thing called?

Answer (score 3):

There are a few options for tubes with internal threads. Some are more expensive than others. You need to decide what may be suitable for your needs.

Here are some examples:

[internally threaded rod](https://www.grainger.com/product/2DLR9?gucid=N:N:PS:Paid:GGL:CSM-2295:4P7A1P:20501231&gclid=Cj0KCQjwpc-oBhCGARIsAH6ote_IhvL31DdcrSsNszsXP6LGD7p8g1tdJae4p4nVvZg3x5ywjTfYHkgaAsV3EALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) self explanatory.

[Internally threaded connectors](https://www.zoro.com/ampg-connect-rod-12-20-int-thrd-3-lg-alum-12-20-thread-to-alum-unfinished-finish-round-link50003ia/i/G0723141/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=surfaces&utm_campaign=shopping%20feed&utm_content=free%20google%20shopping%20clicks&campaignid=19633513665&productid=G0723141&v=&gclid=Cj0KCQjwpc-oBhCGARIsAH6ote_Kzlj7IOLivW2YHuyl53U7Nsh0rbYtRvDA0ow2EXIjL97IW2sKUHUaAr37EALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) These are inserted into tubes to give threads to the ends.

[Tubing inserts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0B7MKKHNC)  Threaded inserts, Shorter, able to hold less weight, light duty.

[Internally threaded stud](https://www.grainger.com/product/2DLX6?gucid=N:N:PS:Paid:GGL:CSM-2295:4P7A1P:20501231&gclid=Cj0KCQjwpc-oBhCGARIsAH6ote-0R5DA0dcHJbIKMSDK8aubMvrfTg-xRsjnfGtejCJq6MaJn69qDngaAkbrEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) Heavy duty.

One of these should satisfy your needs.

Answer (score 2):

The general category is [threaded inserts](https://www.google.com/search?q=threaded%20inserts). To fit a tube, make a plug that fits the end of the tube and install the insert into that.

(Sometimes I really want to post a LMGTFY link...)